# HP Envy Touch Smart Wifi Disabled By Hardware Switch

Tags: networking, wireless

The wifi was fine when i first time install ubuntu 15 and use it a few months until i did something to my machine that i couldn't remember and the wifi is disabled.

when using rfkill it showing:

```
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
```

tried

```
sudo rfkill unlock all
```

but nothing.

i did:

1. Reinstalling ubuntu (wifi still not working)
2. Reinstalling windows (wifi OK)
3. Press wifi key (F12) (not working)
4. Reset BIOS configuration to default (wifi still not working)

any help will be appreciated

**Edit**

```
$ lsmod | grep -e wmi -e lap
hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd                    81920  21 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
wmi                    20480  3 hp_wmi,mxm_wmi,nouveau
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `lsmod | grep -e wmi -e lap`

Comment: @chili555 i edited my question, thanks for your response

Comment: Since the F12 button doesn't now work as expected, I fear that it is a bug in the hotkeys driver *hp_wmi*. If you interrupt the boot process and select an earlier kernel version (and possibly an earlier version of *hp-wmi*) at the GRUB menu, does the F12 key and therefor the wireless start working?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an Ubuntu issue. This is not any driver issue. This is caused by me (and possibly you).

While watching some video... I tried to increase volume with: `Fn + F10` key combination ...
But I mistakenly pressed `Fn + F12` which was `Wifi button` with 'Radio' symbol on it, which disabled my wifi connection.

Running below command in Terminal, you can see the issue:

```
> rfkill list all

0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth           #or whatever it is
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes    
<------ that's because I press Wifi button (above) mistakenly
```

**Solution**: Press again the `Fn + F12` (or, some other key where you have Radio symbol)

Now run again the same command:

```
> rfkill list all

0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth           #or whatever it is
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

    <------ no means solved.
```

Now, go to:

> (Windows button, if you have on the keyboard) > Settings > Wifi > move
> to On > select your Wiki connection to enter credentials

Done, your internet is back on.

Reference = [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/507631)

I hope this works ...